# How to use PHP REST API Wrapper to call a number with an extension?

Tags: php, twilio

I'm trying to make a click-to-call system, based on Twilio's provided tutorial code at http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/click-to-call.

This works great for direct-dial numbers, but I can't figure out how to make it work when the the "to" number (the number that gets dialed first) contains a phone extension (e.g., 212-555-1212 x1234).  I keep seeing references to sendDigits, but I have no idea how to do that from the REST API Wrapper.

I found what appears to be older non-API code that just uses PHP and TwiML which may work (http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/twiml/connect-call-to-second-person) but if it's deprecated, I'd rather build using the modern preferred methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See "Example 3" here:

http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls

You want to pass sendDigits as a parameter, with the digits for the extension.

Comment: I wish their API and its documentation was a little clearer... it's not explicitly stated that the "other parameters" you can pass to the create call method, are the same Optional Parameters you can give the REST API. Thanks so much for this, just saved me a good deal of time.

Comment: Wow... I didn't expect you to be an actual Twilio employee... thought you were one of the countless saints on SO.


Well, it's good to know you guys monitor SO and answer related questions, so you get many bonus points there. Thanks for trying to update the documentation, I would really appreciate that =).